# How to dump DB via cron inside container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, cron, docker-compose

I use `docker-compose` which ups a stack.

**Relative code:**

```
db:
  build: ./dockerfiles/postgres
  container_name: postgres-container
  volumes:
    - ./dockerfiles/postgres/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    - ./dockerfiles/postgres/backups:/pg_backups
```

**Dockerfile for Postgres:**

```
FROM postgres:latest

RUN mkdir /pg_backups && > /etc/cron.d/pg_backup-cron && echo "00 22 * * * /backup.sh" >> /etc/cron.d/pg_backup-cron
ADD ./backup.sh /
RUN chmod +x /backup.sh
```

**backup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Dump DBs

now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M")
pg_dump -h db -U postgres -d postgres > "/pg_backups/db_dump_$now.sql"

# remove all files (type f) modified longer than 30 days ago under /pg_backups
find /pg_backups -name "*.sql" -type f -mtime +30 -delete

exit 0
```

Cron simply does not launch the script. How to fix that?

---

**FINAL VERSION**

Based on @Farhad Farahi answer, below is the final result:

On host I made a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creates Cron Job which backups DB in Docker everyday at 22:00 host time
croncmd_backup="docker exec -it postgres-container bash -c '/pg_backups/backup.sh'"
cronjob_backup="00 22 * * * $croncmd_backup"

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo -e 'Please provide one of the arguments (example: ./run_after_install.sh add-cron-db-backup):
    1) add-cron-db-backup
    2) remove-cron-db-backup'

# In order to avoid task duplications in cron, the script checks, if there is already back-up job in cron
elif [[ $1 == add-cron-db-backup ]]; then
    ( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd_backup" ; echo "$cronjob_backup" ) | crontab -
    echo "==>>> Backup task added to Cron"

# Remove back-up job from cron
elif [[ $1 == remove-cron-db-backup ]]; then
    ( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd_backup" ) | crontab -
    echo "==>>> Backup task removed from Cron"

fi
```

This script adds cron task to host, which launches the script `backup.sh` (see above) in a container.

For this implementation there is no need to use `Dockerfile` for `Postgres`, so relevant part of `docker-compose.yml` should look like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-container
    volumes:
      - ./dockerfiles/postgres/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./dockerfiles/postgres/backups:/pg_backups
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Things you should know:

1. `cron` service is not started by default in `postgres` library image.
2. when you change cron config, you need to reload `cron` service.

Recommendation:

Use `docker host`'s cron and use `docker exec` to launch the periodic tasks.

Advantages of this approach:

1. Unified Configuration for all containers.
2. Avoids running multiple `cron` services in multiple containers (Better usage of system resources aswell as less management overhead.
3. Honors `Microservices` Philosophy.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the Farhad's answer I created a file `postgres_backup.sh` on the host with the next content:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Creates Cron Job which backups DB in Docker everyday at 22:00 host time
croncmd_backup="docker exec -it postgres-container bash -c '/db_backups/script/backup.sh'"
cronjob_backup="00 22 * * * $croncmd_backup"

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo -e 'Please provide one of the arguments (example: ./postgres_backup.sh add-cron-db-backup):
    1 > add-cron-db-backup
    2 > remove-cron-db-backup

elif [[ $1 == add-cron-db-backup ]]; then
    ( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd_backup" ; echo "$cronjob_backup" ) | crontab -
    echo "==>>> Backup task added to Local (not container) Cron"

elif [[ $1 == remove-cron-db-backup ]]; then
    ( crontab -l | grep -v -F "$croncmd_backup" ) | crontab -
    echo "==>>> Backup task removed from Cron"

fi
```

and I added a file `/db_backups/script/backup.sh` to Docker's Postgres Image with the content:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Dump DBs

now=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M")
pg_dump -h db -U postgres -d postgres > "/db_backups/backups/db_dump_$now.sql"

# remove all files (type f) modified longer than 30 days ago under /db_backups/backups
find /db_backups/backups -name "*.sql" -type f -mtime +30 -delete

exit 0
```